# how to convert item in object[] dynamically?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to find a way to convert object[] elements dynamically and find string "needle"
my problem come from first array case

```
  var haystack_1 = new object[]{'3', "123124234", null, "needle", "world", "hay", 2, '3', true, false};
  var haystack_2 = new object[]{"283497238987234", "a dog", "a cat", "some random junk", "a piece of hay", "needle", "something somebody lost a while ago"};
  var haystack_3 = new object[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,7,5,4,3,4,5,6,67,5,5,3,3,4,2,34,234,23,4,234,324,324,"needle",1,2,3,4,5,5,6,5,4,32,3,45,54};

   var index =  Array.FindIndex(haystack_1,item => item.ToString().Equals("needle"));
    Console.WriteLine(index);
```

error

> Run-time exception (line 13): Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.]    at Program.b__0(Object item) :line 13
>   at System.Array.FindIndex[T](T[] array, Int32 startIndex, Int32 count,
>   Predicate`1 match)    at System.Array.FindIndex[T](T[] array,
>   Predicate`1 match)    at Program.Main() :line 13

Comment: I don't see any problem, the 30th index is returned, which is your REAL problem?

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KCr2q3

Comment: @z3nth10n haystack_1  array  null element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is because you are trying to get `ToString` from a `null object`.

In `haystack_1` you have a `null` object:

[image: ...]

```
var index =  Array.FindIndex(haystack_1, item => item != null && item.ToString().Equals("hay"));
```

**Fiddle:** http://rextester.com/JZM30549

This will solve the problem, with this code you will check the object (with `item != null`) before you try to convert anything to a string.

Answer (score 1):

That error occurred because you are trying to get `ToString` from a `null` object.

You can use `Convert.ToString` method which will handle `null` object for you.

**The main difference is that `ToString()` can't handle `null` while  `Convert.ToString()` can handle null value.**

```
var index = Array.FindIndex(haystack_1, item => Convert.ToString(item).Equals("needle"));
```